# php foreach in an array get another field's value

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have this array of std class object:

```
$myarray = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [text] => lorem lorem
                [src] => web
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [text] => ipsum ipsum
                [src] => book
            )
    )
```

and I have a `$value = "lorem lorem"`, that I want to look up in the array and return the `src` of that object.

here is my attempt:

```
foreach($myarray -> 'text' as $key => $text_value){
    if($value == $text_value){
          $new_src = $myarray -> 'src';
    }
}
```

Comment: `$myarray -> 'text'` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to loop through the array and then check the object's `text` attribute:

```
foreach ($myarray as $object) {
    if ($object->text == $text_value){
          $new_src = $object->src;
    }
}
```

This will iterate the array items and grab each `StdClass` object, you can then use that object to compare `text` against `$text_value` and update the `$new_src` if it matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the by `$item->text == $value`

```
$value = "lorem lorem"
$array = array_filter($myarray, function($v) use($value) {
  return $v->text == $value;
});
$srcs = array_map(function($v){return $v->src;}, $array);
print_r($srcs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helpful, I have slightly changed the #1 answer

```
$src = getSrc($myarray, $value);

function getSrc($objArray, $text) {
    foreach($objArray as $obj){
        if ($obj->text == $value)
            return $obj->src;
    }
    return false;
}
```